# Anybody having problem with TouchGestures in Spark AR?

Tags: javascript, instagram, spark-ar-studio

Working on a filter that changes things on tap of an object. Was working minutes earlier then got the following:

> TypeError: TouchGestures.onTap is not a function. (In 'TouchGestures.onTap()', 'TouchGestures.onTap' is undefined) {
>     "line": 47,
>     "column": 0,
>     "sourceURL": "script.js"
>   }

I didn't edit the code while working on some small changes in spark. Here's the following events I'm mapping to touch gestures:

```
TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe(toggleParticles);
TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe(toggleParticleEnvironment);
```

Sounds like I'm not getting access to any methods for touch gestures. 
Is anybody experiencing this now or ever experience something like this with Spark?

Answer (score 6):

i just started having the same issue. super simple script, it was working one minute, then started throwing this error, but nothing changed

here's my code

```
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const TouchGestures = require('TouchGestures');

TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe(function(gesture){
  const x = gesture.location.x;
  const y = gesture.location.y;

  Diagnostics.log(`tap: ${x}, ${y}`);
})
```

[EDIT]

Looks like you need to enable 'Tap Gestures' in the capabilities settings.  Not sure why it worked momentarily, but when I enabled this it started working again
[project/edit properties/capabilites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q3Ss.png)